# Is it wrong to use the dot syntax as a getter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, getter-setter

I know that the . is a shortcut for a setter. Sometimes, I use that kind of code:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"this is row %i", indexPath.row];
```

This works as expected, but I was wondering, is it better (or more correct maybe?) to write

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"this is row %i", [indexPath row]];
```

Or, in other words, should I use the dot syntax only with the = operator, like

```
aTextField.text = @"whatever";
```

Any links/docs are welcome, thanks :)

PS. In case you didn't see the tag, I'm talking about iOS here.

Comment: OK, I'm a bit confused with all the answers. I'll leave the question unanswered for a bit, and I'll wait for more votes. Thanks everyone for the nice discussion though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dot (.) is not only a shortcut for setter, it's shortcut for getter too. You can use dot for getter too. There is no problem, neither this is bad practice. From [Obj-C 2.0 programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW17), "You can use the dot syntax to invoke accessor methods using the same pattern as accessing structure elements. The dot syntax is purely “syntactic sugar”". Note that, it is saying about accessor method, not only setter.

Answer (score 4):

It's a matter of taste.

I prefer not to use the dot syntax for various reasons:

- When using dot syntax, it's much harder to find only the places in your code where you set an value. Search for setValue: is much easier than searching for .value
- As a long time C programmer, my brain is wired to associate the dot syntax with accessing struct members. I find it rather hard to get used to the dot syntax in a different scope.
- The setXY: syntax close follows the natural language much closer. Makes reading someone else's code so much easier.

Comment: It is not just a matter of taste! Dot- or message sending-syntax signals intent.

Comment: Counteracting this down vote too.  I'd up vote again if it were allowed for giving some reasons why dot syntax is a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

"." is a shortcut for accessing a `@property` (which may, by the way, be *readonly*). From the syntax point of view whether this is a getter or a setter depends on the operand position:

```
self.enabled = NO; // setter
BOOL isEnabled = self.enabled; // getter
self.selected = self.enabled = NO; // this is OK too
```

Comment: This is also wrong.  You can declare your properties using an individual getter and setter if you wish.  As long as the method names conform to convention, you can still use dot syntax.

Comment: Agreed. On the other hand, knowing that `self.style` is equivalent to `[self style]` *looks* like relying on implementation details. The mere existence of @property declaration directive *suggests* it is a different thing than a getter/setter method, at least stylistically.

Answer (score 1):

It's coding style so neither is better.

I would note two things though.

As a long time Objective C code I prefer the [indexPath row] as it is consistent with the rest of the code and for a set I would use [aTextField setText:@"whatever"]

But if you need to use the . notation for keypaths the accessing the same variable via method notation in the same piece of code will seem odd.

[Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocObjectsClasses.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW17) says

> Objective-C provides a dot (.) operator that offers a compact and convenient syntax you can use as an alternative to square bracket notation ([]s) to invoke accessor methods.

and

> 

```
myInstance.value = 10;
printf("myInstance value: %d", myInstance.value);
```

> The dot syntax is purely “syntactic
>   sugar”—it is transformed by the
>   compiler into invocation of accessor
>   methods (so you are not actually
>   accessing an instance variable
>   directly). The code example above is
>   exactly equivalent to the following:

```
[myInstance setValue:10]; printf("myInstance value: %d", [myInstance value]);
```

Comment: It is not just a coding style! Dot- or message sending-syntax signals intent.

Comment: Counteracting the down vote.  The reasoning for it is just plain wrong.

Answer (score -2):

Using the dot syntax is not coding style or a matter of taste!

The dot syntax is for accessing properties. The message sending syntax is for dispatching methods. They are conceptually two different things. Legacy and backwards compatibility to Objective-C 1.0 unfortunately makes them interchangeable, which has caused allot of confusion.

Weather to user the dot-syntax or not is dead simple:

- If a public header declares something as **property**, then access it as a property using the **dot-syntax**, as the author of the interface explicitly intended!
- If a public header declares something as a **method**, then access it using the **message sending syntax**, as the author of the interface explicitly intended!
- Make **NO** exceptions.

The hard question is, should you declare something as a property, and thus tell your clients that doit-syntax should be used, or should you declare a method? The simple answer is:

- Use properties for **states** *(is something)*.
- Use methods for **behaviors** *(do/calculate something)*.

Another rule of thumb is that properties should be self-contained, there should be no other way to change the value of the property but to set the property itself. This is Not a hard rule, use common sense, many sensible exceptions exist. For example a `hidden` property that can be changed with `setHidden:animated:` method.

Comment: This is incorrect.  It is totally a matter of coding style.  Message sending is invoked in both cases.  The two syntaxes are not conceptually different and you might get in trouble if you think they are.  In my opinion it was a mistake introducing the dot syntax at all and I never use it even for things I declare with `@property`.

Comment: @JeremyP: Yes both syntaxes will result in a message being sent. But you are completely wrong on them not being conceptually different. It bears to repeat again and again; **properties for state, methods for behavior**. Your personal opinion do not matter, Apple has made up their mind and follows this rule for all their new code (UIKit, etc) and even updates old code (parts of Foundation, etc.). If you want to write consistent and maintainable code then you should too.

Comment: Apple docs themseleves say The dot syntax is purely “syntactic sugar”

Comment: Calling a property with method syntax is hiding the intent, and just as stupid as calling a method using `objc_msgSend(id, SEL, ...)`. Sure in the end the same code is generated both for method syntax, dot-syntax and calling `objc_msgSend()` directly. Avoiding method syntax and do `objc_msgSend()` because you dislike the syntax is just as stupid as avoiding dot-syntax because you dislike the syntax. Code something else or live with it.

Comment: @Mark: In the same sense as generics in Java 5 is *syntactic sugar*, it is there to signal the intention to humans reading the source code, not for the machine that executes it.

Comment: @PeyloW:  I totally agree with your definition of what a property is.  However, the syntax you use to fetch or set that property *is* a matter of style.  The one is syntactic sugar for the other and there are good reasons not to use it if you don't want to.  Apple do not in any sense ban the message passing syntax.

Comment: @PeyloW:  And thye way to signal intent that some artifact is a property is to use the `@property` syntax in the interface declaration.  The `@property` syntax is orthogonal to dot syntax.

Comment: @PeyloW, you should read Obj-C 2.0 programming guide by Apple. It says, "The dot syntax is purely “syntactic sugar”—it is transformed by the compiler into invocation of accessor methods (so you are not actually accessing an instance variable directly). The code example above is exactly equivalent to the following: <example code follows>"

Comment: I'm with @JeremyP on this. I declare properties in header files (partly because other coders expect them, and partly to get auto-generated accessors and mutators) but I rarely, if ever, use the dot syntax for property access (not a big fan of it -- I don't think it should've been introduced, either).

Comment: @taskidor & others: I have read Apple's Obj-C 2.0 guides. I have also looked at Apple's public header-files for new frameworks, all Xcode templates, and Apple's sample code, released since Obj-C 2.0 went public. **It is obvious** that Apple themselves use properties==state and method==behavior. And Apple themselves **always** use properties with dot-syntax, and methods with message send-syntax.

Comment: @all: I am perfectly willing to back on my claim, if you can back up your position with something better than a language document *(As opposed to the Cocoa guidelines)* that conflicts with all the code Apple has release since, or a personal opinions in line with *"I do not like the looks of it"*.

Comment: @all: I am well aware that from a language point of view properties are syntactic sugar. But from a Cocoa perspective they are not. Just as from a language point of view Datasources and Delegates are just protocols, but from Cocoa's point of view they are conceptually different. As long as 'Coding Guidelines for Cocoa' is not updated to include properties or any Obj-C 2.0 features, i choose to see Apple's own source code as authoritative.